# Meu jQuery não está conseguindo trabalhar o json que recebeu do back

Tags: json

Galera, estou desde ontem tentando resolver isso kkk. Bem eu estou fazendo uma requisição ajax para o meu back-end. Até aí tudo bem, os dados chegam e executam certinho, fazem o que eu quero. Eu retorno uma array convertida em Json. Quando eu recebo no meu jQuery, não consigo utilizar como um objeto. Ele sempre da o mesmo erro "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" ou simplesmente fica vazio. Me ajudem Por favor...

Este é o Ajax.

```
$('.inicia-chat').click(function(){
$('#destinatario').val('24');
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/carrega-chat.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
      'destinatario' : 24
    }
  }).done(function(dados_array){
    var parse = JSON.parse(dados_array);
    console.log(parse);
  });
});
```

Este é o PHP

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'kashikoi');
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       $erro = '<script>alert('.$conn->connect_error.')</script>';
   }

$consulta_mensagem = "select * from mensagem where id_destinatario = ".$destinatario."";
$consulta_m = $conn->query($consulta_mensagem);

$rows = $consulta_m->num_rows;

$array = array();

if($rows <= 0){
    echo 1;
}else{
    while($linha = $consulta_m->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $wow = array($linha['id_destinatario'], $linha['id_remetente'], $linha['mensagem']);
        array_push($array, $wow);
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: Precisas mesmo do JSON.parse?

Comment: Como o Sérgio disse, aparentemente `dados_array` já chega sendo um objeto, não mais uma string JSON, então não precisa fazer o parse do mesmo.

Comment: Adicione um dataType : "json". No objeto que vai como parâmetro de $.ajax()

Comment: Galera, eu tentei as duas sugestões e ainda não deu certo :/ Muito obrigado

Comment: O pior é que se eu tiro aquele while e passo um objeto simples ele funciona, o problema é quando tem um objeto dentro do mesmo.